# I can't catkin_make

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

system:vmware15.5pro ubuntu18.04.2 ros melodic

```
Base path: /home/liu/testpkg
Source space: /home/liu/testpkg/src
Build space: /home/liu/testpkg/build
Devel space: /home/liu/testpkg/devel
Install space: /home/liu/testpkg/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/liu/testpkg/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/liu/testpkg/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic

-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/liu/testpkg/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7

-- catkin 0.7.20
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - learning_topic
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'learning_topic'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(learning_topic)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:94 (message):
  add_message_files() directory not found:

  /home/liu/testpkg/src/learning_topic/msg
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  learning_topic/CMakeLists.txt:80 (add_message_files)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:530: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

and i found a solution of commenting out the following lines,which didn't work

```
## add_message_files
## add_service_files
## generate_messages
```

what should i do?

here is the error log:

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



 Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_9f8ac/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/build
    make[1]: 进入目录“/home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeT

mp”
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c


 Linking C executable cmTC_9f8ac
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/cc      -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_9f8ac 
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o：在函数‘main’中：
    CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x1b)：对‘pthread_create’未定义的引用
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


     CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f8ac.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_9f8ac' fail
    
    ed
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_9f8ac] Error 1
    make[1]: 离开目录“/home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp”
    Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_9f8ac/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_9f8ac/fast] Error 2
    
    File /home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:

    /* */
    #include <pthread.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      (void)argv;

#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
    #else
      (void)argc;
      return 0;
    #endif
    }
    
    Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
    Change Dir: /home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_a5267/fast"

    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a5267.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a5267.dir/build
    make[1]: 进入目录“/home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp”
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a5267.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
    /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a5267.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c

Linking C executable cmTC_a5267
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_a5267.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_a5267.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_a5267 -lpthreads 
    /usr/bin/ld: 找不到 -lpthreads
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_a5267.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_a5267' failed
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_a5267] Error 1
    make[1]: 离开目录“/home/liu/testpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp”

Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_a5267/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_a5267/fast] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344886/i-can%27t-catkin_make/) by [流水疾翔](https://answers.ros.org/users/51973/%E6%B5%81%E6%B0%B4%E7%96%BE%E7%BF%94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message states:

> ```
> add_message_files() directory not found:
> ```

```
  /home/liu/testpkg/src/learning_topic/msg
```

Does a directory called `msg` exist in `/home/liu/testpkg/src/learning_topic`?

What is the output of `ls -al /home/liu/testpkg/src/learning_topic/msg`?

> ```
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> ```

```
  learning_topic/CMakeLists.txt:80 (add_message_files)
```

As a check: can you show us the lines in your `CMakeLists.txt` around line 80?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [流水疾翔](https://answers.ros.org/users/51973/%E6%B5%81%E6%B0%B4%E7%96%BE%E7%BF%94/) on 2020-02-24**:
thanks for your answer.
i solve this question by recovery the image of the early space of the vm,and i try second time.at this time,it works,without the exist of dictionary msg and Personmsg in it.
i am so puzzled and wondering what have happeded...but as a new learner i can't figure out why.
by the way,the 80 line of the Cmakelist is the same as what it is being when created.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-24**:\

> By the way,the 80 line of the Cmakelist is the same as what it is being when created.

If you want us to help you, you'll have to show us the code. We cannot guess what you see.